# Simple question about characters in django urls

Tags: django, unicode, ascii, idn

In django documentation they wrote that in urls it is only possible to use ASCII characters. It seems to be strange to me because of characters that are in IDN domains. For exapmle, if I have IDN domain and I want to have not only ASCII characters in urls, it is really impossible by default to do this in easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but so what. Python supports [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) natively.

```
>>> 'xn--' + u'たとえば'.encode('punycode') + '.com'
'xn--r8j2b1a7a.com'
```

Comment: So what if it is impossible? I am not expert but I think that if the answer is true there is some work to do for django creators and developers if they want to keep thinking about django as friendly framework in user's minds.

Comment: If you can identify specific issues with Django then I'm sure that the developers would be most interested to hear about them.

Comment: I don't see problems now but only possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround is to ask Django to match the URL as '.' regexp raw string, since it does not understand '\w' to mean your character set of UTF-8 etc.

So in urls.py you can write 'foo/bar/.+' instead of 'foo/bar/\w+' which is exclusive for English speakers, as it were. I'm just kidding.

Goodluck.